# when update data where id=$row[id]

Tags: php, where-clause

I want to update data row
But the problem is that it is updated All rows

this is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM emp 
                          JOIN inv ON emp.name=inv.empname 
                      WHERE inv.empname='".$name."'") 
                or die ("mysql error query");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$updatestartdate = date('d/m/Y');
$updateenddate = date('d/m/Y');
$status = $_POST['status'];

while ($rowshow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $timetoshow = unix_time($rowshow['timex']);

    //UPDATE
    if (isset($_POST['Update']) and $_POST['Update'] == 'dataupdate'){

        $updatestatus = mysql_query ("UPDATE inv SET 
                                     updatestartdate='$updatestartdate',
                                     updateenddate='$updateenddate',
                                     status='$status' 
                                     WHERE id='".$rowshow['id']."'")
                        or die ("updatestatus Error");

        if (isset ($updatestatus)){
            echo "<div class='hidecontent'><h3 style='background-color:#3F3F3F; padding:5px;' align='center'>
                <font color='#FFFFFF'>Update is done</font></h3><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='5; url=cpanel_user.php' /></div>";
        } else  {
            echo "<div class='hidecontent'><h3 style='background-color:#FF0000; padding:5px;' align='center'>
<font color='#FFFF00'>Update Error</font></h3></div>";
        }
    }
```

Where is problem?

Comment: Where are you getting `$name` from?

Comment: It will update all rows because in while you have passed a rowshow[id] you will need to pass $id

Comment: It is **totally unclear** what your code is actually doing and more importantly **what it should be doing**. Take a break and then refactor your code so that it makes sense.

Comment: @khanAsim, I really doubt this is the reason. Can you elaborate your concerns?

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right. I'd advise you to remove everything but the failing query statements and briefly explain each parameter (like where it does come from, what type is it and etc)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean to say that he is updating the records in the while loop so if he needs to update a single row with the id he needs so he need to write it seperately

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
"UPDATE inv 
 SET updatestartdate='$updatestartdate',
     updateenddate='$updateenddate',
     status='$status' 
 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's updating all the rows then it probably means that you are not filtering the data which is to be updated. To filter the data, use the `WHERE` clause. Next ensure that all rows don't have a duplicate values else it would update all the rows as well. Consider the following code:

```
UPDATE `database` . `table` SET `Name` = 'Zahid Saeed' WHERE `Name` = 'Zahid';
```

The point is, the person named 'Zahid' is not alone in this world.  You have to be more specific. If you can, always use the ID column to update a value as it is always unique just like so:

```
UPDATE `database` . `table` SET `Name` = 'Zahid Saeed' WHERE `id` = 'Some ID'
```

If you can't get the ID, use the `AND` clause to match multiple columns to filter the data more accurately like this:

```
UPDATE `database` . `table` SET `Name` = 'Zahid Saeed' WHERE `Name` = 'Zahid' AND `Age` = 19 AND `Email` = 'abc@hotmail.com'
```